# Winforms dialog title indentation without icons

Tags: c#, winforms, indentation, title

We are currently redoing our dialogs and this is a question about design in Winforms.
We decided to don't use icons in the title of each dialog. But now we have this weird indentation before the title text. Is there a way to delete this indentation (pls look at the green line)...

Thanks in advance.

[image: dialog]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about WinForms but in classic Win32 you'd process the WM_NCPAINT message and draw the frame the way you want it. You can process Win32 messages in WinForms but the details escape me at the moment (but easy to search for an answer). So you'd do something like:-

```
func Handle_WM_PAINT (args)
{
    call default drawing handler
    redraw the title bar the way you want it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is C# application then, Change form border style to SizableToolWindow.